# Robot sliding in idle state when spawning in gazebo

Tags: gazebo, urdf

As the title mentioned, I built a robot using urdf. However when I spawned it into gazebo it start slowly sliding backward. I tried adding friction into the code but it seems to do nothing. Also I've noticed my inertia is slightly tilting forward and the wheel part being square (I've calculated using the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia#List_of_3D_inertia_tensors)). Maybe that's the reason it's sliding?  Down below is my urdf file and inertia showed in gazebo.
[image: gazebo inertia]
forklift.urdf.xacro:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="forklift">

    <link name="base_footprint"/>

    <link name="base_link">
        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
            <mass value="50.0"/>
            <!--
            <inertia ixx="0.05" ixy="0.05" ixz="0.05" iyy="1.3419385416666667" iyz="1.3419385416666667" izz="2.296875"/>
            -->
            <inertia ixx="1.3419385416666667"
                iyy="1.3419385416666667"
                izz="2.296875"
                ixy="0.0"
                ixz="0.0"
                iyz="0.0"/>
        </inertial>
        <visual name="">
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.525 0.525 0.2155"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="blue">
                <color rgba="0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0"/>
                <texture filename=""/>
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.525 0.525 0.2155"/>
            </geometry>
            <!--
            <surface>
                <friction>
                    <ode>
                        <mu>100</mu>
                        <mu2>100</mu2>
                    </ode>
                </friction>
            </surface>
            -->
        </collision>
    </link>
    <gazebo reference="base_link">
        <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
    </gazebo>
    <joint name="base_joint" type="fixed">
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
        <parent link="base_footprint"/>
        <child link="base_link"/>
    </joint>

<!--    ***   wheels   ***   -->    

    <xacro:macro name="wheel" params="name x y">
        <link name="wheel_link_${name}">
            <inertial>
                <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
                <mass value="1.0"/>
                <!--
                <inertia ixx="0.05" ixy="0.05" ixz="0.05" 
                    iyy="0.0009333333333333333" iyz="0.0009333333333333333" izz="0.0018"/>
                -->        
                <inertia ixx="0.0009333333333333333"  
                    iyy="0.0009333333333333333"  
                    izz="0.0018"
                    ixy="0.0"
                    ixz="0.0"
                    iyz="0.0"/>
                </inertial>
            <visual name="">
                <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <cylinder radius="0.06" length="0.02"/>
                </geometry>
                <material name="black">
                    <color rgba="0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
                    <texture filename=""/>
                </material>
            </visual>
            <collision>
                <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <cylinder radius="0.06" length="0.02"/>
                </geometry>
                <!--
                <surface>
                    <friction>
                        <ode>
                            <mu>100</mu>
                            <mu2>100</mu2>
                        </ode>
                    </friction>
                </surface>
                -->
            </collision>
        </link>
        <gazebo reference="wheel_link_${name}">
            <material>Gazebo/Black</material>
        </gazebo>

        <joint name="wheel_joint_${name}" type="continuous">
            <origin xyz="${x} ${y} -0.100250" rpy="1.57 0.0 0.0"/>
            <parent link="base_link"/>
            <child link="wheel_link_${name}"/>
            <axis xyz="0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
        </joint>
    </xacro:macro>

<!--   ***   fork base   ***   -->
    <xacro:macro name="fork_base" params="name y">
        <link name="forkbase_link_${name}">
            <inertial>
                <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
                <mass value="0.5"/>
                <!--
                <inertia ixx="0.05" ixy="0.05" ixz="0.05" 
                    iyy="0.0005208333333333334" iyz="0.0004208333333333334" izz="0.00010833333333333334"/>
                    -->
                <inertia ixx="0.0005208333333333334"  
                    iyy="0.0004208333333333334"  
                    izz="0.00010833333333333334"
                    ixy="0.0"
                    ixz="0.0"
                    iyz="0.0"/>
            </inertial>
            <visual name="">
                <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <box size="0.01 0.05 0.1"/>
                </geometry>
                <material name="green">
                    <color rgba="0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0"/>
                    <texture filename=""/>
                </material>
            </visual>
            <collision>
                <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <box size="0.01 0.05 0.1"/>
                </geometry>
            </collision>
        </link>
        <gazebo reference="forkbase_link_${name}">
            <material>Gazebo/Green</material>
        </gazebo>

        <joint name="forkbase_link_${name}" type="fixed">
            <origin xyz="0.2675 ${y} -0.10025" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
            <parent link="base_link"/>
            <child link="forkbase_link_${name}"/>
        </joint>
    </xacro:macro>

<!--   ***   fork   ***   -->
    <xacro:macro name="fork_link" params="name">
        <link name="fork_link_${name}">
            <inertial>
                <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
                <mass value="0.5"/>
                <!--
                <inertia ixx="0.05" ixy="0.05" ixz="0.05" 
                    iyy="0.00010833333333333334" iyz="0.0026083333333333336" izz="0.0027083333333333334"/>
                -->
                <inertia ixx="0.00010833333333333334"  
                    iyy="0.0026083333333333336"  
                    izz="0.0027083333333333334"
                    ixy="0.0"
                    ixz="0.0"
                    iyz="0.0"/>
            </inertial>
            <visual name="">
                <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <box size="0.25 0.05 0.01"/>
                </geometry>
                <material name="green">
                    <color rgba="0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0"/>
                    <texture filename=""/>
                </material>
            </visual>
            <collision>
                <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <box size="0.25 0.05 0.01"/>
                </geometry>
            </collision>
        </link>
        <gazebo reference="fork_link_${name}">
            <material>Gazebo/Green</material>
        </gazebo>

        <joint name="fork_link_${name}" type="fixed">
            <origin xyz="0.13 0 -0.045" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
            <parent link="forkbase_link_${name}"/>
            <child link="fork_link_${name}"/>
        </joint>
    </xacro:macro>

<!--   ***   combine component   ***   -->
<!--
    <xacro:wheel name="back_right" x="-0.150000" y ="-0.272513"/>
    <xacro:wheel name="back_left" x="-0.150000" y ="0.272513"/>
    <xacro:wheel name="front_right" x="0.150000" y ="-0.272513"/>
    <xacro:wheel name="front_left" x="0.150000" y ="0.272513"/>
-->
    <xacro:wheel name="back_right" x="-0.150000" y ="-0.272513"/>
    <xacro:wheel name="back_left" x="-0.150000" y ="0.272513"/>
    <xacro:wheel name="front_right" x="0.150000" y ="-0.272513"/>
    <xacro:wheel name="front_left" x="0.150000" y ="0.272513"/>

    <xacro:fork_base name="right" y ="-0.055"/>
    <xacro:fork_base name="left" y ="0.055"/>

    <xacro:fork_link name="right"/>
    <xacro:fork_link name="left"/>

</robot>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your robot slides backward because you did not specify damping and friction coefficients of wheel joints. Try this:

```
<joint name="wheel_joint_${name}" type="continuous">
    <origin xyz="${x} ${y} -0.100250" rpy="1.57 0.0 0.0"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="wheel_link_${name}"/>
    <axis xyz="0.0 0.0 1.0"/>

    <dynamics damping="0.7" friction="0.1" />
</joint>
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks